# the difference between Connections_connected and thread connected in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, database-connection

[Mysql Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NnXH.png)
 some times a get max_user_connections exceeds and ispite of this i can make a connection and other thing is how many currently connections being used . how do i know that please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `‘max_used_connections’` variable defines the total number of connections that have been in use simultaneously since the server was started.

This variable is different when compared to the variable `‘max_connections’`. 
The system variable `‘max_connections’` defines the maximum permitted number of simultaneous connections by a client.

You can find the maximum connections after which the connections will be refused by using the formula `(Max_used_connections/max_connections)`. You can refer various monitoring services like MONyog which defines these terms well.